# DTW, question about the initialization of C[0,0]

Tags: python, dtw

I read the function of DTW calculation here :
https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/dtw.html

In my opinion, one of these 2 following lines get something wrong :

```
C[0, 0] = 0.
dist = d(x_i, y_j) ** 2
```

Or for the simple dtw on [0] and [1], you will not have 1 as answer. So both possible corrections :

```
C[0,0] = d(x_0, y_0) ** 2
```

or

```
dist = d(x_{i-1}, y_{j-1}) ** 2
```

I think it's the second solution if we want to  generalize it.

Answer (score 0):

The text specifies that the pseudo code assumes time indices starting at 1,
and in fact the main loop starts at 1.
Therefore, that `C[0,0] = 0` initialization is correct.
The first cells of the cost matrix will look like this:

```
0   | inf | ...
inf | inf | ...
...
```

and when the following line is evaluated for `i = 1` and `j = 1`

```
C[i, j] = dist + min(C[i-1, j], C[i, j-1], C[i-1, j-1])
```

the `min` function will simply return zero,
and `C[1,1]` will simply have the value of the first computation,
i.e. `dist`.

This is a common way to implement DTW,
that's also the way it's described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).